# pass variable to resize() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs "#sidebar-wrapper" and ".j1". I am finding the height of ".j1" on window load, j1 changes size according to its content, now I have to apply this height to "#sidebar-wrapper".

I have tried this

```
var currentHeight = 0;
$(window).load(function() {
 //get the natural page height -set it in variable above.

  currentHeight = $('.j1').outerHeight();

  console.log("set current height on load = " + currentHeight);

 $("#sidebar-wrapper").resize(currentHeight);  
});
```

I don't know what to use to set height of "#sidebar-wrapper".

Comment: `$("#sidebar-wrapper").height(currentHeight);`

Comment: this is working but on every alternate page-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use next code example in order to get and set attributes cause may be  your  `$("#sidebar-wrapper")` is not exists yet(length 0 in jquery object):

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

           currentHeight = $('.j1').outerHeight();    
           console.log("set current height on load = " + currentHeight);    
           $("#sidebar-wrapper").css('height',currentHeight );
           console.log($("#sidebar-wrapper").height());

        }, false);
```

Comment: This is also working but still not all the time. When it doesn't work I have to reload the page again

Comment: @rk11501 What do you it is not working all the time? This event will be triggered only once on DOMContentLoaded... What exact solution to you need?

Comment: I have links for 2 pages(A,B) both are using the js code for height. I load A it works, then I click on link for B, sidebar-wrapper of B takes the height of A but if I reload B, it takes the correct height.

Comment: @rk11501 Do you have $('.j1') on you B page???
 I suppose on reload B page you $('.j1') is 0, thus you will get initial (correct) height of $("#sidebar-wrapper").

Comment: @rk11501 If you want to do use case like: from A go to B, and if the user reload B -> get $('.j1').outerHeight(), you should pass it via url params and them on B page load check if there is something in url params from A page.. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the CSS attribute **height** of **#sidebar-wrapper**?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmbhof1o/2/)

`$("#sidebar-wrapper").css("height", currentHeight);`

.resize method seems to be an event triggered when changing the size of your window. You can find more information about the resize event here: [Resize Event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/).

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $( "#log" ).append( "<div>Handler for .resize() called.</div>" );
});
```